# Third party API and IHostingEnvironment in Application layer?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate, abp

I have 2 queries related to the open source version of aspnetboilerplate.

- If I am implementing some services that will call some other third party API APIs, where do I implement those? In application layer directly or Do the code for calling third party API in Core layer and then expose them as service using application layer?
- How do i get IHostingEnvironment .EnvironmentName in Application and core layer? Based on the Environment, i need to call the API keys stored in appsettings.json 
  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use appservices for your third party integration.
- you cannot use web based references (eg: IHostingEnvironment) in Application or Core layer. This breaks layer isolation. you can use `appsettings.Development.json` or `appsettings.Staging.json` for your different environments. asp.net automatically reads settings from the corresponding environment. but if you have extra requirement that's related to web layer. you can pass it as a parameter to your appservice method from web layer.